# Excel: How to show top 3 "winners" by age and gender?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to use Excel to manage the data for a marathon. The marathon groups winners by `age` and `gender` into a `category`, and awards prizes for first to third place in each `category`.

**Can Excel be used to determine the winners dynamically, by entering the data on a single worksheet, and having the results automatically calculated and shown on another worksheet in some way?**

I've got a single worksheet that contains the following data for each row:

`name, age, gender, age category, overall rank`

I'm open to VBA and Excel function based approaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to update worksheet2 when the data in worksheet1 is modified, you could use VBA to create a resultant page that is dynamically updated.

- In the developer tab click visual basic.
- Expand the Microsoft Excel Objects folder and view the code for Sheet1
- Create a new function called:

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_ChangeByVal Target As Range)
  EndSub
  ```

This function is called whenever the data in worksheet1 is modified.

To update the data based on the rankings column and making these assumptions:
The data is within these columns Name: column A, Age: column B, Gender: column C, Category: column D, Overall Rank: column E 
 
Within the Worksheet_Change sub compare the value in column E, the ranking column and transfer the row contents if the competitor has placed within the top four positions.

```
'If data is changed within column 5 (ranking column), repopulate worksheet2
If Target.Column = 5 Then
    'Remove all of the old rows except the header
    Sheets(2).Rows("2:" & CStr(Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count)).EntireRow.Delete

    'For each row on worksheet1 check if the value in column "E", if the ranking column is less than 4, if it is copy the row onto worksheet2
    Dim rowCounter As Integer: rowCounter = 1
    For i = 1 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 1
        If (Sheets(1).Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value < 4 And Sheets(1).Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value <> "") Then
            Sheets(2).Range("A" & CStr(rowCounter + 1)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value
            Sheets(2).Range("B" & CStr(rowCounter + 1)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("B" & CStr(i)).Value
            Sheets(2).Range("C" & CStr(rowCounter + 1)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("C" & CStr(i)).Value
            Sheets(2).Range("D" & CStr(rowCounter + 1)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("D" & CStr(i)).Value
            Sheets(2).Range("E" & CStr(rowCounter + 1)).Value = Sheets(1).Range("E" & CStr(i)).Value
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        End If
    Next i
End If
```

Insert a sorting algorithm here if it is required, after the data has been migrated.

If you need more details or help with the sorting please let me know.

Comment: This is the approach that works best for how I like things to work... I'll post back and update to your answer when I'm done. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's a spreadsheet that does the above. Thanks for the suggestion! I merged the "category" and "age" into a single category "Age Category" that's used to do this. Changing the "Placement" column regenerates the "Winners" sheet using the categories list defined on the "Configuration" sheet

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8aikva8m8mgzby/winner_by_gender_and_category.xls?dl=0

Comment: Nicely done, that would have been my approach too for sorting the data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. What you describe is a pivot table. Click a cell in your source data tabe, insert a pivot table hit OK. By default it will be created in a new sheet. Drag Age group, gender and name into the row area and rank into the value area.

Right-click any of the names in the pivot and use Filter > Top 10. Assuming that the top rank is 1, Change the "Top" to "Bottom", 10 to a 3 and you'll end up with something similar to this:

[image]

If you base the pivot table on an Excel Table (that has been created with Insert > Table), then you can add data to the source table, refresh the pivot table (on the Pivot tools ribbon) and the current results will show.

A copy of the file is [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=fe479525195477f7!3467&authkey=!ALlxez2i2ezmKgE&ithint=file%2Cxlsx).

Comment: Sweet.. this sounds alot like what I was hoping I could do. I'll try this out tonight and let you know... much appreciated!

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get the Pivot Table to sort correctly on the ranking. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing! Could you post your example spreadsheet somewhere? Maybe I could work it out from there. Thanks!

Comment: I added a link to a sample file.

Answer (score 1):

for age category you can try to group them together using

```
=IF(*ConditionForCatI*,CatI,IF(*ConditionForCatII*,CatII,...)))
```

until all the category is filled. After that choose filter under data. This will enable you to sort them by the age group or gender. (e.g. if you want to sort by gender) :

1. click the down arrow besides the gender heading
2. select only male or only female
3. click the down arrow besides the timing heading (I assume you will have timing heading to decide the winner)
4. Sort from A to Z since it will show the smallest to the biggest and award winner will be the smallest timing

Do the same for other category and you can find your awards winners.

Cheers